# Android: StaleDataException - Crashed on Ice cream sandwich OS

Tags: android, cursor, staledataexception

I have a problem with ice cream sandwich OS. Our application works fine on previous OS when pause and resuming the applicaiton. When I used on Ice Cream Sandwich, it crashed when I tried to resume the activity from the background.

It gave me an error saying StaleDataException about attempt to access on cursror that has been closed. It didn't happen on previous OS when I tried on the emulator. When I used new OS on the emulator, this error occurs.

It is very frustrating because i don't know where it causes this. I am using the managedQuery to query the thumbnails in the gallery. I heard that it got deprecated and used the CursorLoader instead. I am not sure is this the reason but I thought new OS should compatible with old OS as well so using managedQuery should be no problem. As it mention using CursorLoader, is there a change the old OS won't functioning.

Does anyone encounter this problem before and got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not your case but I had a problem like this when using managedQuery because I was closing the cursor manually.

As stated in the [ManageQuery definition on developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#managedQuery(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String)) the activity manage the lifecycle of the cursor returned by managedQuery, you shouldn't close the cursor manually.

Hope it helps